# Graphviz: align nodes horizontally

Tags: graphviz, dot

I thought the following would be simple, but for some reason, it really isn't...

Let's start with this:

```
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR
    A -> B -> C -> E -> F
}
```

This is the output:

[image]

Now, let's add a backwards relationship:

```
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR
    A -> B -> C -> E -> F
    E -> A
}
```

I get this:

[image]

In the end, what I want is for the nodes to be aligned horizontally, and the backwards arrow to go around. I'm thinking, easy, with `rank=same`:

```
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR
    {rank=same;A -> B -> C -> E -> F}
    E -> A
}
```

Oops:

[image]

Now, it's not even aligned horizontally or even sequentially (it's E, F, A, B, C). So how do I get a layout as in the very first output, with an arrow from E to A going around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
digraph G {
    //rankdir=LR
    {rank=same;A -> B -> C -> E -> F}
    E -> A
}
```

the `rank=same` forces  the `LR`

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it! I wouldn't have thought that `rankdir=LR` and `rank=same` where (sort of) incompatible!